# Connecting to google cloud datastore using go

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to connect to cloud datastore from Go. I used the sample code given here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang.

These are the relevant bits of my code:

```
func getCtx() context.Context {
    // Initialize an authorized transport with Google Developers Console
    // JSON key. Read the google package examples to learn more about
    // different authorization flows you can use.
    // http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google
    opts, err := oauth2.New(
        google.ServiceAccountJSONKey("CassandraTest-key.json"),
        oauth2.Scope(datastore.ScopeDatastore),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //titanium-goods-766 is the project id for CassandraTest (under sthilakan@eyeota.com)

    ctx := cloud.NewContext("titanium-goods-766", &http.Client{Transport: opts.NewTransport()})

    // Use the context (see other examples)
    return ctx
}

type contactInfoEntity struct {
    EmailKey  *datastore.Key
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}

func main() {
    ctx := getCtx()
    fmt.Println("successfully got context", ctx)

    err := putEntity(ctx, "fname1", "lname1", "email1")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("success")
    }
}

func putEntity(ctx context.Context, firstName string, lastName string, email string) error {
    key := datastore.NewKey(ctx, "contactInfoEntity", email, 0, nil)

    contactInfoEntity := contactInfoEntity{
        EmailKey:  key,
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName:  lastName,
    }

    _, err := datastore.Put(ctx, key, &contactInfoEntity)

    return err
}
```

I get this error consistently.

```
Error: error during call, http status code: 403 Unauthorized.
```

I have disabled and reenabled datastore api a few times (as suggested here: [All Requests return 403 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885347/all-requests-return-403-unauthorized)). I have also tried removing and adding the service account.

(I tried to connect my compute engine instance to datastore using the steps here - https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs and it works fine).

Have anyone connected to cloud datastore from go ?

Regards,
Sathya

Comment: Connecting to `Cloud Datastore` also requires the ScopeUserEmail scope. Can you try again with `oauth2.Scope(datastore.ScopeDatastore, datastore.ScopeUserEmail)`?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it works after adding datastore.ScopeUserEmail. Go documentation needs to be updated to reflect this. Can you please post it as an "answer" and I will make it as the correct answer ?

Comment: Is this the documentation you were looking at? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/blob/d104d801a8b7b8fdfe6150c6362218286555c5da/datastore/example_test.go#L43 I'll see about getting it updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing Cloud Datastore requires two scopes: `datastore.ScopeDatastore` and `datastore.ScopeUserEmail`:

```
opts, err := oauth2.New(
    google.ServiceAccountJSONKey("CassandraTest-key.json"),
    oauth2.Scope(datastore.ScopeDatastore, datastore.ScopeUserEmail),
)
```