# How do I connect to Google Cloud Datastore in golang from a GCE VM?

Tags: go, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When I try running [these example functions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/blob/master/datastore/example_test.go) to connect to Cloud Datastore, I get a 401 Invalid Credentials error.

I'm running the go code from a VM within a Google Cloud Project. I have enabled the Datastore API and generated a JSON key which is loaded by the example code.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479833/connecting-to-google-cloud-datastore-using-go) is very similar and even mentions the same repo, but does not use the same authentication shown in the examples, and was related to a 403 Unauthorized error.

For some reason the Datastore documentation does not mention go outside the context of App Engine.

Comment: As a first step, I'd suggest filing an issue on the gcloud-golang project: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm really nervous to file an issue on a big project like that but I will give it a shot. Hopefully it's not a silly mistake on my end.

Comment: Issue logged: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/issues/212